# How to find quickly duplicate dictionaries in the list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, for example:

```
list_of_clients = [
    {"Name": "Alex", "Surname": "Dorfman", ...},
    {"Name": "Serge", "Surname": "Ioffe"}, ...
]
```

and I know that there are duplicate dictionaries in the list for the same client.

Is there any way to print them out quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: What defines a duplicate in this case? All key/value pairs are identical? Just the `'Name'`? Both `'Name'` and `'Surname'`?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @CoryKramer: all items of dictionaries are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a `set` of already seen names. You have to define which keys should be considered. In this case : `["Name", "Surname"]`. Simply add more if you want:

```
list_of_clients = [{"Name": "Alex", "Surname": "Dorfman"}, {"Name": "Serge", "Surname": "Ioffe"}, {"Name": "Alex", "Surname": "Dorfman"}, {"Name": "Serge", "Surname": "Ioffe"}]

already_seen = set()

for client in list_of_clients:
    complete_name = tuple(client.get(k) for k in ["Name", "Surname"])
    if complete_name in already_seen:
        print("Duplicate : %s" % (complete_name,))
    already_seen.add(complete_name)
```

It outputs:

```
Duplicate : ('Alex', 'Dorfman')
Duplicate : ('Serge', 'Ioffe')
```

Comment: Problem being, I don't think the Name and Surname are the only keys... `{"Name": "Alex", "Surname": "Dorfman", ...}` (OP's example, note the ellipsis)

Comment: @Coldspeed Also note that the whole syntax was incorrect. My method is flexible. If there are more interesting keys, simply add them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
res = set(tuple(client.items() 
                for client in list_of_clients 
                if list_of_clients.count(client) > 1))
```

The `set()` will get rid of duplicates in the result, and the `tuple()` is required (at least in Python3) because the items() themselves are still not hashable.

As others mentioned this will not keep the items in order, but if you just want to remove the duplicates this is sufficient.

Comment: It would be better to use `if list_of_clients.count(client) > 1 and client not in list_of_clients`, such that the duplicates only appear once in the list, and not each time they occur. (Not my downvote though)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `client` is always in `list_of_clients`, it's better to use a set then.